# jenkins powershell check if job ran in last 60 minutes

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I would like to have a build scheduled in Jenkins that runs every 60 minutes, that is the easy part. When the build runs I want to know if a build that is "Triggered remotely" has been started within the past 60 minutes. If the Triggered remotely build has not been started within the past 60 minutes, I want this build to fail so that an alert (failure email) is sent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use groovy script to decide.due to time constraints i couldn't provide you the exact code snippet.
eg:scm is for scm changes.

```
def buildTrigger JenkinsAPI.thisBuild.Trigger
if (buildTrigger == scm)
```

jenkins  maintains timer to run jobs at mentioned period(as like crontab in unix).
So possible ways to find whether jobs are started at 60 mins is:

write a script to validate  the jobs interval
or maintain a job to validate  the job interval.